# .net reference dependency when doing unit testing

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

a [TestClass] was written in C#. the namespace `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` was used and a reference added `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework`. subsequent, clean solution and rebuild solution were clicked.
then, an error occurred when rebuilding the solution. 
the warning msg (which was not copied into the clipboard) refers to a missing reference `System.Web`. When adding this reference, a notification was displayed that the target framework will be retargeted to 4.0. 
`System.Web` was added. Build succeeded.

displayed error messages were complaining about [TestClass] (not known) - these messages were not suitable. therefore, the warning message was temporarily related to this issue.

Afterwards i wanted to read the messages again. removed `System.Web` reference. (and cleaning the solution) Now it is going to build without `System.Web`. Also in .net 4.5.

btw vs 12 is used. it's a WPF application.

What exactly did the trick beside of temporarily adding a reference like `System.Web`?

Comment: Do you ahve any AseemblyRedirect section in .config file?

Comment: some thing like this  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Windows.Forms" publicKeyToken="B77A5C561934E089" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>

Comment: Please post the .config along with the question?

Comment: it (.config) includes only a connection string for sql server. no assembly redirects.

Comment: is WPF browser Application or WPF window Applcation.?

Comment: If you don't mind can u reproduce the same issue in Sample Applcation, sahre in sendspace.com

Comment: that's the point and my question if somebody had already this issue. it occurred only once.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29645/discussion-between-akshay-joy-and-mnemonic)

Answer (score 0):

I got the Same error Like this, Please check this section in your .Config

If you use .Net 4.0

```
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web" publicKeyToken="B77A5C561934E089" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
          </dependentAssembly> 
 </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```